# Do we have Merge functionality in Data Flow Azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

What i am trying to do on Azure Data flow is that Source data update to my destination database It may Update records or enter new rows respect to source data.

I know we have similar functionality in SSIS package called merge, but I am not sure we have that functionality on data Flow, so is it someway around we can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not called Merge, but you can achieve what you want by using the Join transformation.

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join It even mentions SSIS merge and compares to it.

Hope this helped!!